# If equation a holds and equation b does not hold is it necessary for a+ b to not hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, logic, absolute-value

I've been using this trick a lot lately, I can't seem to prove why it works.  E.d. (using an inequality here, but point still remains)

:

$$|x-a| \ge |x| - |a|    \tag {1}$$

add $$|x|+|a|\ge |x-a|$$

$$|a|\ge|a|$$

Therefore, $(1)$ is true.

Comment: You tried to show $\beta\ge \gamma$ from $\alpha\ge \gamma$ and $\alpha\ge \beta$. This won't work, for example if $\alpha=3$, $\beta=1$, $\gamma = 2$.

Comment: @RobertZ aye but I was asking whether it's right  to prove things this way. I haven't quite seen this done in any textbook I've read

Comment: let x=3 ;a=4  then we have you saying:

$$|3-4|\ge|3|-|4| $$ aka $$1 \ge -1$$
$$|3|+|4|\ge|3-4|$$ aka $$7\ge  1$$
and
$$|4|\gt-|4|$$    true only because the negative sign is outside the absolute value.   three nearly unrelated statements.

Comment: a further example would be  x=3;a=-1 then we get $$5\ge2$$ $$4\ge5$$ second one clearly false, and  we would have gotten ( if not for your edit)  $$1\gt-1$$

Comment: STOP!  using it!!!!!  It is false and you have been lucky so far that it has worked.  All you are doing is proving that something is not mind numbingly obviously false.  That does not mean it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

$$\text {unknown inequality}+\text{true inequality} = \text{true inequality}$$

and concluded that the unknown inequality is true. This does not work in general. Take

Unknown inequality: $2>3$

True Inequality: $5>1$

If you add these up you get a true inequality, $7>4$. But as you see this doesn't mean that the unknown inequality must've been true.

---

Now with equations it's a different matter.

Suppose you have

Unknown equation:$a=b$

True equation: $c=d$

True equation: $a+c=b+d$

To see that the unknown equation is true, just do

$$\text{second true equation} - \text{first true equation}$$

You know that both equations are true so the result of this must be true. But the result is $a=b$, the unknown equation!

Comment: Oh! Damn I see.

Comment: I wonder what addition does to the logical validity of the statement, like why does it work for equalities?

Comment: @Vrisk I edited the answer with that information Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh man, this makes so much sense! Thank you. I now appreciate inverses even more. Like this doesn't work with inequalities because there's no 'inverse'  because it's not one to one. Pretty neat

Comment: @Vrisk Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Just $|x-a|+|a|\geq|x-a+a|=|x|$.

By your reasoning we can prove that $4>5$.

Indeed, since $3>1$ we "obtain":
$$3+4>1+5,$$
which is true.

"Hence", $4>5$.